# Create image file (Base64 to blob) using Google Appscript

Tags: google-apps-script

I have created a function using Google appscript that convert base64 to blob and then use the blob to create a file into my Google drive folder. However, the file is created but no image is displaying.

Here's my code:

```
function base64toBlob() {
  var currentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("--My Google Drive ID--");

  var base64 = "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";
  var decoded = Utilities.base64Decode(base64);
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(decoded);

  Logger.log(blob); // Returns blob

  currentFolder.createFile("A Blob Title", blob, "image/png");

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var blob = Utilities.newBlob(decoded, MimeType.JPEG, "nameOfImage");
currentFolder.createFile(blob);
```

Give that a go, I did something similar. Hopefully helps :)

Comment: Thank you! This works. In Google api they set the 3 params you've set in the createFile function, but doesn't work. However setting in newBlob works. Nice find!